# Getting the return of a store Insert

Tags: extjs, store

Ive created a store, which I can manipulate.

```
var storeJ = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    root: 'data',
    idProperty: primaryKey,
    id:'storeJ',
    fields: [primaryKey,'name', 'code', 'email'],
    autoSave:true,
    storeId: 'storeJ',
    proxy: proxyJ,
    writer: writer,
});
storeJ.load();
```

When I try to add to this store, via a button, I return a Pk ( via php )
This happens after
    storeJ.insert(0, r);

```
//Tbar Item
handler: function(){
  var r = new storeJ.recordType({   });             
  grid.stopEditing();
  storeJ.insert(0, r);
  grid.startEditing(0, 1);
}
```

I assume I need some kinda listener to get there, but how on earth do I create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ensure you pass a object in your return, and that the root of the store is correctly pointed to the right object.
Simply returning 1 or so won't work, you need to return json_encode($return['data']=>1); or its equivalent in the above defined store.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the record before the insert.

Will something like the following work:

```
var r = new storeJ.recordType({   });  
r.data[primaryKey] = pk;           
grid.stopEditing();
storeJ.insert(0, r);
grid.startEditing(0, 1);
```

Comment: The thing is that due to the autosave firing, the pk only gets returned during the save that happens when  storeJ.insert(0, r); is called.